# Eclipse Missing Properties

Tags: java, android, css, xml, eclipse

I am working on a project out of an Android Boot Camp book. The project is called Healthy recipes. It is being made in eclipse using graphical layouts. On my first .XML file everything is working fine. I have The Properties options on the bottom right and the over lay on the top showing "Configure, Emulator, next state, app theme, class, locale, and what version." [image]

Now the problem is, is that on my second .XML file we create which is "recipe.xml" It is not wanting to show properties for any of the layout. Which the properties is used to change text size, background color etc. I am new to making things using graphical layouts in eclipse. If anyone knows why the properties and the over lay on the top showing version is not showing it would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

-Aaron

Comment: the recipe.xml is inside layout folder or xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Save the recipe.xml. Maybe something is not generated correctly yet.
2. Restart the development environment. Sometimes this solves the problem.
3. Open and compare the XML view for both activities. Try to figure out if there is a mistake in your second XML
4. If you can't find any difference, post the XML content of recipe.xml here.

Comment: I went ahead and followed these steps, but that wasn't the problem. I just went ahead and deleted the recipe.xml and made a new one, which somehow fixed the problem. I don't know what messed it up the first time, but it was resolved.